# bash round to nearest multiple of 4

Tags: bash, rounding

I need to get nearest multiple of 4 after dividing number of lines by 25.

```
   line= wc -l < file.txt
   # 47322487 lines

   parts= $line/25
   # 1892899.48 after division

   round 1892899.48 this to nearest multiple of 4.
```

Comment: What value are you wanting to get as output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty easy way to handle it is to divide by 100 first then multiply by 4 after adding 50 to round the number.

```
expr '(' $line + 50 ')'  / 100 '*' 4
```

Comment: Well done for handling the rounding correctly (I forgot!). If you're going to use shell arithmetic, I think it'd be better to go with `echo $(( (line + 50) / 100 * 4 ))` rather than using `expr`.

Comment: Good solution, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you solve this entire problem using awk:

```
awk 'END { print int((NR / 100) + 0.5) * 4 }' file.txt
```

This divides the number of lines by 25 * 4 then uses `int` to round the result, before multiplying back by 4.

0.5 is added so that values are rounded to the nearest value. To always round down, you can remove it and to always round up, you can add 1 instead.

Comment: This method gives the wrong result for most negative numbers. Adding 1 instead of 0.5 to always round up gives the wrong result when the number is a multiple of 4, or for example `awk '{print int(($0/4)+1)*4}'<<<4` prints 8. When 0.5 is not added, negative numbers are rounded up instead of down, or for example `awk '{print int(($0/4)+1)*4}'<<<-3` prints 0.

Comment: @nise given that the original question was about rounding the number of lines in a file, the solution didn't take into account negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Round to the nearest multiple of 4, rounding both 6 and 10 to 8.

```
awk '{print sprintf("%.0f",$0/4)*4}'
```

Round to the nearest multiple of 4, always rounding numbers whose modulo for 4 is 2 or -2 up.

```
jq -R 'tonumber/4+.5|floor*4'
```

Round to the nearest multiple of 4, always rounding numbers whose modulo for 4 is 2 or -2 up, assuming that all numbers are nonnegative. This gives the wrong result for most negative numbers.

```
awk '{print int(($0/4)+0.5)*4}'
```

Round up to a multiple of 4.

```
awk '{print$0+(n-$0%n)%n}' n=4
perl -MPOSIX -lpe'$_=ceil($_/4)*4'
```

Round down to a multiple of 4.

```
awk '{print$0+(n-$0%n)%n}' n=-4
perl -MPOSIX -lpe'$_=floor($_/4)*4'
jq -R 'tonumber/4|floor*4'
awk '{i=int($0/4);print((i==$0||$0>0)?i:i-1)*4}'
```

Round positive numbers down to a multiple of 4 and round negative numbers up to a multiple of 4.

```
awk '{print int($0/4)*4}'
```